# how to type TypeScript function which extends some properties in object array?

Tags: typescript, generics, tuples

```
type Person = {
  firstName: string;
};
interface ExtendedPerson extends Person {
  lastName: string;
  age: number;
}

const personArr: Person[] = [
  {
    firstName: 'John',
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Jane',
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Joe',
  },
];

function assignTwoPropertiesToObjectArray<
  OA,
  P1 extends string,
  P2 extends string,
  V1,
  V2,
>(
  objectArray: OA[],
  propertyNames: [P1, P2],
  defaultValues: [V1, V2]
): (OA & { [key1 in P1]: V1 } & { [key2 in P2]: V2 })[] {
  return objectArray.map((obj) => {
    return {
      ...obj,
      [propertyNames[0]]: defaultValues[0],
      [propertyNames[1]]: defaultValues[1],
    } as OA & { [key1 in P1]: V1 } & { [key2 in P2]: V2 };
  });
}

const result = assignTwoPropertiesToObjectArray<
  Person,
  'lastName',
  'age',
  string,
  number
>(personArr, ['lastName', 'age'], ['Doe', 30]);

const extendedPerson: ExtendedPerson[] = result;
```

In the above example, I just wrote assign**Two**PropertiesToObjectArray function with tuple type.
However, I wanna write assign**Properties**ToObjectArray function which operates regardless of the number of properties.
The point is that I can determine what types of properties' value with generics.
How can I type this function?